# How to know which version of ROS still be updated?

Tags: ros, rosversion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I use ROS electric and fuerte.

I want to know how long will ROS support earlier version.

Is there any doc or mark to tell us which version of ROS still be supported(means still be updated)?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40756/how-to-know-which-version-of-ros-still-be-updated?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[REP-0003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) describes ROS releases and for which Ubuntu distribution they are available. ROS releases will probably get updated *at most* as long as their Ubuntu distribution [reaches end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

In practice, once released ROS versions will only get bug fixes, but there's no guaranteed date until that happens. I would say it strongly depends on the stack maintainer. Bugfixes for releases should at least be supplied as long as the current ROS release is the latest one.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3